# Can't add new Activity to a library project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using a library beside my project, the library contains lots of activities.
But now when I try to add new activity via ADT Template wizard, it stops at last step of "New Activity" and doesn't close dialog.
When I cancel that dialog I see it only added the activity definition to manifest and nothing else.

Comment: What if you manually add the file, or using right click > new > file

Comment: Yes I can added manually, but I need the wizard to work! @Mdlc